# What is the best and fastest way to compare a column based on the other column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

There are two columns as "hour" and "passenger" in a dataframe.

```
df
+------+------+-----------+
| id   | hour | passenger |
+------+------+-----------+
| 1    | 11   | 4         |
+------+------+-----------+
| 2    | 12   | 5         |
+------+------+-----------+
| 3    | 23   | 6         |
+------+------+-----------+
| 4    | 15   | 4         |
+------+------+-----------+
| 5    | 12   | 3         |
+------+------+-----------+
| ...  | ...  | ...       |
+------+------+-----------+
| 2234 | 10   | 2         |
+------+------+-----------+
```

The below code does not work.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.hist(df.hour, df.passenger )
plt.title('passenger vs hour') 
plt.xlabel('passenger')
plt.ylabel('hour')
```

How to change this code? Or other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: `df.hist(by='hour', column='passenger')`?

Comment: What about the code doesn't work? What are you trying to do and what is the error message.

Comment: It is nice you included an example of your dataset, but if you include a sketch/cartoon of your expected output, based on your example dataset, you will get better help sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your x and y labels reflect what you actually want to plot, then a histogram doesn't make sense here; you might want a bar chart.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

id = [1,2,3,4,5]
hour =[11,12,23,15,12]
passenger = [4,5,6,4,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id, hour, passenger)), 
                  columns=['id', 'hour', 'passenger'])
plt.bar(df.passenger, df.hour )
plt.title('passenger vs hour') 
plt.xlabel('passenger')
plt.ylabel('hour')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
   Unnamed: 0   id      hour    passenger   Unnamed: 4
0         NaN       1      11            4         NaN
1         NaN       2      12            5         NaN
2         NaN       3      23            6         NaN
3         NaN       4      15            4         NaN
4         NaN       5      12            3         NaN
5         NaN    2234      10            2         NaN
```

You can try this command:

```
dframe.plot()
```

[image]

or this one :

```
dframe2.plot.bar(x=' hour ', y=' passenger ', rot=0)
```

[image]